# Why VS Code intellisence for Unity is not working in Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with intellisense on vs code for Unity on Ubuntu 22.04. I have a lot of extensions for vs code so that may be the problem.

I tried to open a file in Unity for vs code. Using external tools setting. It worked but I want to have intellisense too.

Comment: welcome to SO. If you expect some help we will need to provide more detail of what you tried. The exact steps you followed with the results you expect and the results you obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this shouldn't depend on any other extension you have installed. Could you go through following checklist and confirm everything is setup correctly?

##### VSCode Unity 3D working IntelliSense checklist:

- Have the [Mono Framework](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) and [.net SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) installed on your machine
- Make sure in Unity3D the external Editor is set to "Visual Studio Code" and press regenerated project files if nessacary
- Have the C# extensions installed in VSCode
- Either in the project settings or globally have `omnisharp.useModernNet` disabled
- Check if the Path to `mono` is correct in your VSCode setting for `omnisharp.monoPath`
- Ensure the OmniSharp Server is running when you open up the Solution

##### Further debugging

- Check the Output of your OmniSharp/C# Console in Visual Studio and check the error messages.
- There is a [bug in the C# extension](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5454) in Version `v1.25.2` with Mono Path. I can work with `v1.25.0` very fine so far.

---

I hope this helps you to find the issue on your machine.

Comment: `dotnet --list-sdks` does not show any installed sdks even though I used snap to install it as "dotnet-sdk", i prefer the LTS version 6.0 but 7.0 is also fine.

Comment: But the intellisense still worked, So thank you!